# IE7/8 text not displaying correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am at a loss as to why text which is coded as black in the style-sheet is not appearing in the input box. If I highlight the text however, I can see the text there. It's almost like it is displaying the text in the same color as the input background. To make this easier to understand, I have included 2 grabs to show the problem. You will see that the text is there if I highlight the text. There are no opacity or filters being used in the style-sheet. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful. Thanks

[image: Text incorrect and not displaying]

[image]

css code

```
#boxaddform fieldset input
        {

        color: #000000;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 390px;
        height:20px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-left:20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
       }
```

Comment: Please show your css.

Comment: if you have your code as rgba rgb it wont work on IE 7-8 need to be hex

Comment: @jycr753: There is no support for `rgba` in older browsers, but `rgb` definitely works since IE7, and even earlier.

Comment: show your css and html

Comment: hmm show some code them

Comment: What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: does get over writing on the console, pressing F12?

Comment: @jycr753 sorry? do not understand your comment

Comment: check the developer console on IE, and see if that element it is being over writing for another value, or if the style sheet it is being applied, pressing F12 on IE

Comment: That piece of CSS looks fine. Likely you have some other CSS that is also affecting the element.

Comment: check by placing the color in style attribute of input field like `style="color:#000000"` . if that works then check is there any condition css files included for ie 7 and 8. or any css classes overriding this